# What is the meaning/interpretation of the constant term of the higgs potential?

Tags: higgs, symmetry-breaking

In Higgs context, after electroweak symmetry breaking,
the Higgs doublet field is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ v+H\\ \end{array}\right)$$

If we develop the Higgs potential $\mu^2\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi+\lambda\left(\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi\right)^2$, we will have constant term in the Lagrangian after the symmetry breaking: $\frac{1}{2}\mu^2v^2+\frac{\lambda}{4}v^4$.

What is the *meaning/interpretation* of the constant term of the Higgs potential?

Comment: It's a constant shift in the potential and hence has no bearing on the dynamics of the theory, no?

Comment: @Nihar Karve : I ask the question because I *don't* know. Do you mean that this constant is *not important* and *has no interpretation*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constant term in Lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296803/constant-term-in-lagrangian)

Comment: @Nihar Karve : I do know that constant terms will not have consequence after derivation of Euler-Lagrange equations. I would like to *check* that in context of Higgs physics, there is "*nothing to say*" about this constant term.

Comment: Constant terms in the action play no role in QFT. They do have consequences in gravity (cosmological constant).

Comment: @Prahar Mitra : thank you. Would you with hands why this is important in cosmology : are we "skipping" the Euler-Lagrange equation ? (the derivative of the constant would give 0, isn't it ?)

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian - In GR, the action is $S = \int d^d x \sqrt{-g} {\cal L}$ so if I shift ${\cal L} \to {\cal L} + \Lambda$ we have $S \to S + \int d^d x \sqrt{-g} \Lambda$. The extra term in $S$ depends on the metric so such a term contributes to Einstein's equations, but not to matter equations of motion.

Comment: @Prahar Mitra : a big thank you for sharing your knowledge.